# Froala Editor getting crash while editing

Tags: angularjs, wysiwyg, froala

I'm using Froala editor in AngularJS 1.6, When I add HTML from code view and try to edit from view mode, editor getting a crash.

It's working fine in my local system where I using WampServer with Window 10, When I deploy on NGINX with centos 7, It will be crash

For more details please check the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSc_WOx7Lic)

editor version: froala_editor v2.8.1

Answer (score 2):

I'm also facing with your problem, and today I had a trick to handle it.

You can refer [my answer for my question on StackOverflow here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879399/froala-editor-crash-after-11-times-model-changed-in-react/53882021#53882021)

I guess you've use CSS to hide the unlicense banner of Froala, so it will be crash after model changed 11 times. This is my simple demo to detect this problem 
 https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-froala-editor?file=style.css.

```
div.fr-wrapper>div>a {
        /* display: none !important; */
        /* position: fixed; */
        /* z-index: -99999 !important; */
    font-size: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}
```

In the CSS code, if we use `display: none`, it will be crash after 11th change. You can try if you use `display: none`, after you edit, it will crash after 11 times.

I found a trick how to handle this problem, I don't hide banner, but I set it is invisible by `font-size: 0` and `padding: 0` as my code above.