# Froala Editor crash after 11 times model changed in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, socket.io, froala

I've built a simple editor online without identity, implemented in backend with *Node.JS with Socket.IO, MongoDB*, and client using *React* connecting Socket.IO.

To create editor, I've used [**Froala Editor**](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) with [*react-froala-wysiwyg*](https://github.com/froala/react-froala-wysiwyg) as plugins for React.

I've deployed my app on Heroku at https://dontpad.herokuapp.com and it's working fine with multiple user (Socket works fine).

This is my screenshot about how it worked with 7 user online once time, and it work when someone changes data:

[image]

## Error

But I detected that after the Froala Editor after changed **11 times**, **the Froala editor crash**, and I don't understand what is happening?

This is the screenshot after model of Froala changed **10 times**, and it's still working:

[image]

And when I changed it at **11th**, it crashing:

[image]

**The error on console is:** (error only appears after about **5s** since the editor crash - LoL)

> froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'VOID_ELEMENTS' of null
>       at Object.f [as isEmpty] (froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:7)
>       at Object.E [as get] (froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:9)
>       at froala_editor.pkgd.min.js:19

## Source code

This is my repo on github https://github.com/huynhsamha/dontpad

This is my code rendering `Froala Editor`

```
<FroalaEditor
            tag="textarea"
            model={this.props.model}
            config={configFrolaEditor}
            onModelChange={this._onChangeModel}
          />
```

I used `Redux` to map state to props to child component so `model={this.props.model}`.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  model: state.Model
});
```

And this is `_onChangeModel` which emit to socket and call **`this.props.editModel(model);`**, which is `mapDispatchToProps`

```
  _onChangeModel = (model) => {
    this.timeShowTextSaving = Date.now();
    this.props.editModel(model);
    this.setState({ stateModel: msg.SAVING });
    socket.emit(conf.socket.client.modelChanged, {
      model, room: this.room
    });
  }


// This is mapDispatchToProps
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  editModel: (model) => {
    dispatch(actions.editModel(model));
  }
});
```

This is [full version of this file - **Editor.jsx**](https://github.com/huynhsamha/dontpad/blob/master/client/src/components/editor/Editor.jsx)

And this is **[my config of Froala Editor Component](https://github.com/huynhsamha/dontpad/blob/master/client/src/utils/FroalaWysiwyg.js)** Is there something wrong in my configuration?

```
export const config = {
  placeholderText: 'Edit Your Content Here!',
  spellcheck: false,
  scaytAutoload: false,
  charCounterCount: false,
  theme: 'custom',
  indentMargin: 10,
  heightMin: window.screen.availHeight,
  fontFamily: {
    // fonts ...
  },
  toolbarButtons: [
    'bold', 'italic', // buttons ...
  ]
};
```

Has anyone encountered this problem like me?

Comment: hello, i highly recommand you to contact the Froala support, they will be better help

Comment: I've found the solution for my question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the answer for my question.

I've tried with simple version using Froala Editor with React and Redux on https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-froala-editor?file=style.css and I've found why it's crashing after 11 times.

Because Froala is using with license, but I've using CSS to remove the banner of Froala so when the 11th change, editor will crash.

I've tried with hidden version (hide license banner) and with no hidden, and the hidden version is crash after 11 times.

I also found a trick how to handle this problem, I don't hide banner, but I set it is invisible by `font-size: 0` and `padding: 0`

```
div.fr-wrapper>div>a {
        /* display: none !important; */
        /* position: fixed; */
        /* z-index: -99999 !important; */
    font-size: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    height: 0px !important;
}
```